# Can't figure out the cause of Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int when stored procedure runs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that calls a custom scalar-valued function. When I run the stored procedure, I get an error:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int error

I have been trying to figure out the cause of the error by debugging the stored procedure and stepping through it line by line. I still cannot pin it down.

In SSMS, I have a query:

```
USE [TESTDB]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[buildEventSum]

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

When I debug and step into buildEventSum, then step through it, the error does not get generated until it returns to the above query and you "step over" the select 'return value' line.  Confirmed that @return_value is 0, so I am stumped.

Any tips on how to go about isolating and identifying the cause would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Should "SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value" really say this "SELECT  @return_value as 'Return Value'"

Answer (score 0):

For scalar function, you use SELECT:

```
SELECT [dbo].[buildEventSum]() AS result;
```

Or if you want to save the result to a variable:

```
DECLARE @result int;
SET @result=[dbo].[buildEventSum]();
SELECT @result AS result;
```

Comment: the above was generated by SSMS's execute stored procedure.  buildEventSum is a stored procedure that does many things including call a scalar function with the following code:

Comment: update eventsum
    set ontest = case when (edate < ontestdate) then 0 
                      when (offtestdate is null) then 1
                      when (edate > offtestdate) then 0
                      else 1
                 end,
  
  weight = case when (dbo.Median_wt(feeder,edate,rfid) = 0) then 0
               else (dbo.Median_wt(feeder,edate,rfid))
     end